# Ionic 4: the ion-content element's height changes when input is focused and user is scrolling

Tags: css, ios, ionic-framework, scroll, ion-content

I found that when an input element is focused and the user is scrolling up or down, the height of the `ion-content` would have an increase in height which is basically equal to the height of the input element. If a textarea is focused, then the height would be largely increased and the user will be able to view a big blank space at the bottom, which will disappear instantly once the scrolling action is over.

I was not able to check how exactly the height of element is changed, as the `height` attribute isn't changing when I was using safari to inspect it while scrolling. Please let me know if there's a way to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Test device: iOS 15.4, iPhone 13